# Best way to manage static text on views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have some views that has paragraphs of static text. It doesn't look right to have those text  directly on the view. Is there a better place to put the static text except the database?

Comment: In your locale.yml files maybe? Using I18n or something else

Comment: You could place it in the layout file, `application.html.erb` by default.

Comment: see rails guides for details on the `I18n.translate` helpers - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#internationalizing-your-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly discourage the use of the database and *strongly encourage* I18N - check out the guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

if your content is dynamic. Store it into a database 
if your content needs to be translated in multiple languages, store as `YML` files in locales.

However,
if its just static text.
I would advise you to create rails partial for each of the paragraphs of static text & then `render` them into main view. this way you get nice separation between your view code & content without overly complicating things.

Comment: static text is used in too many places and creating a partial for each of them seems like a overhead. don't you think so?

Comment: well, how many lines of text are we taking about here? and it all at same places? what are the average number of lines of text per action/view? IMHO, All these kinds need to be taken into account while deciding what is an overhead & what is not :-)